# Argparse: compute default from positional argument

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a parser wherein one of the default values for an optional argument can be readily computed from one of the positional arguments, and one might *occassionally* want to use a different value. Is it possible to defer the computation of the default value with argparse?

Comment: What do you mean by deferring the computation of the default value? Can you give us a few examples?

Comment: Usually it's easier to use the default `default`, `None`, and add interactions like this after parsing.  You can't, with `argparse`, force the user to provide the `positional` before the `optional` (or v.v.).

Comment: @blhsing i.e., if positional argument X has the value Y1 then the default value for the optional argument Z will be T1, if X=Y2 then Z=T2, and so on.

Comment: @hpaulj The order doesn't matter between the arguments to me, see above

Comment: The parser sets the defaults at the start of parsing.So it can't assign a different default to Z based on the value of X.  Unless you use 2 parsing passes.

Comment: Okay, appreciated.